# system call sleep not working correctly

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

I tried to use the system call "sleep" both in Ubuntu 14.04 and in `Raspian (Raspberry Pi 2B)` in order to delay code execution for e.g. 5 sec. However, surprisingly, all code in front of the system call "sleep" within Delay is not executing at all during runtime. Here is the simple code which caused the problem:

```
using System;
using Gtk;
using Mono.Unix.Native;            

public partial class MainWindow: Gtk.Window
{
    public MainWindow () : base (Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
    {
        Build ();

        entry1.Alignment = 0.5f;

        // This code is not executed:
        double result = Math.Pow (2.0, 2.0);
        entry1.Text = result.ToString ();
        // End of code not executed

        // Code executed:
        Delay (5);
        entry1.Text = "Button-A";
    }

    protected void OnDeleteEvent (object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
    {
        Application.Quit ();
        a.RetVal = true;
    }

    private Int16 Delay (UInt32 value)
    {
        Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall.sleep (value);    
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Do I misunderstand basic things of Linux or am I facing a compiler error? Thanks for any hints to the subject!

Answer (score 0):

You are blocking on the main UI thread.

Instead of using a system exec to block/delay execution, use `Task.Delay` instead.

```
await Task.Delay(5000);
```